# make a write_only field conditionally required in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a field in my serializer which is required conditional on value of another field.
say `password` is required only if `registerField` is `email`.

I have this serializer

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ...
    password = CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    def validate(self, data):
        if 'email' in data.keys() and 'password' not in data.keys():
            raise ValidationError({'password', 'this field is required'})
        return data
```

this method works, but the response is:

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "{'this filed is required', 'password'}"
    ]
}
```

When I remove write_only I get

```
{
    "password":["this filed is required"]
}
```

which is what I want to get with `write_only`

versions:

```
djangorestframework==3.8.2
django==2.2.12
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': "this field is required"})` instead of `raise ValidationError({'password': "this field is required"})` in validate method. Check [Object-Level-Validations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation)

```
from rest_framework import serializers
  ...
 
     def validate(self, attrs):
        if 'email' in attrs.keys() and 'password' not in attrs.keys():
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': "this field is required"})
        return attrs
```

Above is just a quick solution in your case, but DRF provides single field-level validation methods too.

Note: for using this **ValidationError** as per DRF:

The recommended style for using `ValidationError` is to keep it namespaced
under `serializers`, in order to minimize potential confusion with Django's
built-in `ValidationError`. For example:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
raise serializers.ValidationError('Value was invalid')
```

[Field-level-validations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation)

You can write `def validate_password(self, data):` method too, in which you can raise `ValidationError("field is required")` with all validations regarding a particular field if `(required=True)` in serializer field.

In field-level validation request data can be retrieved from using this statement.

```
request_data = self.context['view'].request.data
```

Comment: I'm already importing `ValidationError` from `rest_framework.serializers`. I don't see how this makes difference. Also, field-level validation can't access other fields in the `data` param.

Comment: do you know why just `serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)` doesn't work?